# Eclipse Web Service Client Project Type?

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, project

I created a basic Java project in Eclipse then added a Web Service Client using the File->New "Web Service Client" wizard.

This generated my stubs correctly and I am able to connect to the web service, however, I get the following error/warning when I run:

*WARNING: Unable to find required classes (javax.activation.DataHandler and javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart). Attachment support is disabled.*

I then tried to create the client using a Dynamic Web Project (instead of a basic Java project) and the error went away.

This is obviously due to the fact that the Dynamic Web Project includes libraries that are not included in a basic Java project.

My question is, why do I need to make a Dynamic Web Project (it seems like overkill) just to make a web service client? Is there some *simpler* project type you would recommend using?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is just a warning, you could leave it as is. To make it go away, you could look up the jars that contain those classes and add them to your project.

I think we normally use a JavaEE project type, and that may bring in some extra library files. I wouldn't normally think you need a dynamic web project to make the error go away.

The only difference in the project type is the Libraries included automatically for you when you start them. You can start any project as a Java project and then in the Project Properties, Build Path, Libraries tab add additional libraries to the project.

Both of the missing classes above are in the j2ee.jar file, so if you can add that jar to your build path of the project it should go away.